# Unable to send multipart/form-data with REACT to MySQL

Tags: reactjs, multipartform-data, form-data, multipart-mixed-replace

I am unable to send image and form data to mysql. My backend is in Java and when using postman it works fine. I am unable to do so when I send it from the frontend. I have input fields for username, title, description et al as well as the image. Please help where I am wrong. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, you are trying to send the file name which is wrong. You have to append the file like:

```
var file = event.target.files[0];

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);

formData.append("var1", val1);  // Other fields

await fetch("url", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
}).then({
// code here
}).catch({
// code here
});
```

And on the server side you will get the file in `file` or whatever name you have provided at the time of appending it in the formdata.

Comment: handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    selectImageFile = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            picture: event.target.files[0]
           
        })
    } this is my event handler

Answer (score 0):

Please use this tricks

***React:*** convert your media file to base64 string.

***Java:***  convert base64 to image(img,pdf,xlxs,etc...)

Converting image to Base64(REACT.JS):

```
function convertBase64(url, callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onload = function () {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function () {
                    callback(reader.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
            };
            xhr.open('GET', url);
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.send();
        }

        convertBase64("path-of-the-image/user_picture.png", function (dataUrl) {
            //console.log('RESULT:', dataUrl);
        });
```

Converting Base64 to image(JAVA):

```
// Needed Imports
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;


def sourceData = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPAAAADwCAYAAAA+VemSAAAgAEl...==';

// tokenize the data
def parts = sourceData.tokenize(",");
def imageString = parts[1];

// create a buffered image
BufferedImage image = null;
byte[] imageByte;

BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
image = ImageIO.read(bis);
bis.close();

// write the image to a file
File outputfile = new File("image.png");
ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
```

Comment: any recommendations on youtube or articles.